# XML String can't be parsed to SimpleXMlElement

Tags: php, xml

I want to create a SimpleXMLElement from a XML string, but the code breaks with the message `String could not be parsed as XML`.

So i tried to figure out where the error in my string is, but I'm not able to find it. The strange thing is that it's working fine on [phpfiddle.org](http://www.phpfiddle.org).

This is the code I'm trying to run:

```
<?php
$obj = new SimpleXMLElement('<auction><auctionMode>shopProduct</auctionMode><categoryId>3345</categoryId><auctionName>TESTENTRY The finding of the "Third eye”.</auctionName><quantity>2</quantity><condition>new</condition><description>cdata_This is a testentry from me, do not buy! sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</description><payoptions></payoptions><shipmethods></shipmethods><priceBuyNow>22</priceBuyNow><salesTax>7.00</salesTax><prodCatId>620311</prodCatId><ifSoldOut>display</ifSoldOut><isApproved>1</isApproved><noIdentifierFlag>1</noIdentifierFlag><weight>0.90</weight><images></images></auction>');
var_dump($obj);
?>
```

Sadly the errorlog doesn't give me any further information for this error.

I also tried to set the `<auctionName>` within a `<![CDATA[]]>` tag, but this didn't change anything. I was guessing that it's because of the `”` in the `<auctionName>`
, but I'm not to sure anymore since it's working on phpfiddle.

What is wrong with this xml?

Comment: works fine on my end too, also [online](http://codepad.viper-7.com/8lmiyX)

Comment: @Ghost The online site works for me too. But not my script on my server. I have no clue why it won't work.

Comment: @derp I'll try that. And i fixed the "titles" to the right XML tag, sorry for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the errors that happen during XML parsing with [`libxml_get_errors()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-errors.php)

Example:

```
<?php
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$sxe = simplexml_load_string("<?xml version='1.0'><broken><xml></broken>");
if ($sxe === false) {
    echo "Failed loading XML\n";
    foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
        echo "\t", $error->message;
    }
}
?>
```

**edit**

Looking closer at your text, your error might be coming from: `"Third eye”`

Because you are using a MS-Word kind of closing quote character.

Comment: Both you and @Derp are right. It was an encoding problem, never thought about that one. I fixed it! Thanks!